# Variable declaration and clearing any previous info residing within it...how to?

Tags: c

I was hoping to get help with the below question.

In VBA programming there is a syntax which can be used to assign the value vbNullstring to a variable before you assign any data to it, this way you ensure a fresh start to your variable and the data saved onto it.

How do you do the above in C language? I'm currently running a step-by-step debug of my code and I've added a few 'watch' processes to my key variables so that I can keep track of what my code is assigning it. Here's my confusion and hence the above question...my program has not even begun to assign any data to my variables and yet on my 'watch' tab i see that these variables are carrying different values already like 19924000669 for int variables and "(\0\002\0\0\0Ay..." for char variables. How do I get rid of these initial values and show an empty initial value for all my variables before the code assigns any data to it?

Thanks,
J

Comment: "In VBA programming there is a syntax which can be used to assign the value vbNullstring to a variable before you assign any data to it, this way you ensure a fresh start to your variable and the data saved onto it." - pretty sure this is utter nonsense.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of some code in VBA where the "vbNullString syntax to ensure a fresh start to your variable" prevents an error (or does something else useful)?

Comment: you can use it for what ever purpose you need.

 Dim x1 As String

        x1 = "Hi!"
        Label1.Text = x1

        x1 = vbNullString

Comment: In `Dim x1 as Integer : x1.text = "Hi!"` I don't see anything about vbNullString, nor about cleaning variables for a fresh start.

Comment: @immibis 'I kept pressing enter as I was trying to edit the above.' vbNullString is a syntax we can use in VBA to clear whatever data was saved previously in an object, or variable. What I want to know is what is the equivalent of that in C language?

Comment: You know that `vbNullString` is just a long way to write `""` in VBA?

Comment: @immibis since we're being technical> not exactly although the two bring about the same end result they are not the same. "" uses a length of 0 but still takes up memory. (It assigns the value 0 to the variable) while vbNullString allocates no memory into the variable or object. If the two were the same they wouldn't co-exist even after all this time VBA has been around. Regardless I was only trying to figure out how to do the same in C. Cheers!

Comment: You might be looking for NULL then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "initial" values in C. Or rather, there are no meaningful values - C doesn't require that the compiler initialize variables to any value (some compilers do, so it depends on the compiler - read your compiler manual).

What you're seeing is "noise". When you turn on your computer, the value of data in your RAM is random. Set by various physical processes from thermal noise to cosmic background radiation. Also, when you're running a program in an OS, when you free some memory back to the OS or when your program quits the OS generally doesn't reformat that memory to any value. So you may also be seeing data that's there from previous running programs.

The traditional solution in C is to initialize the variable with the value zero (`0`) or if it's a pointer, `NULL`.

If you need to know if something is actually data or uninitialized then use a struct with a member (something called `defined`?) that keeps track of the initialized state and set that to `0` or `1`. That's what VB (or Javascript or Perl etc.) is doing behind the scenes anyway.

C doesn't have the "feature" of undefined values because C deals directly with hardware. And bits are either on or off - digital electronics doesn't really like any other values - so variables muse be either `0` or not `0`.

Comment: Note that some people consider initializing pointers with `NULL` to be an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable you can specify an initial value, e.g.

```
int intvar = 0;
char str[10] = "";
```